# How to reverse a video and audio clip with moviepy?

Tags: python, mp4, moviepy

I've been trying to reverse a mp4 file so that it outputs another mp4 file but in reverse. The problem I've been having is that I can only get it to reverse the video by exporting each of the frames as pngs then reimporting them in reverse order, but this doesn't include audio data. Is there a better way to reverse a mp4 file?

Comment: I don’t know the command off the top of my head, but I bet ffmpeg has an easy way to do it. Moviepy can do it, but ffmpeg would be much faster.

Comment: Ill try ffmpeg, Ill tell you if it works! Thanks.

Comment: I tried doing it using ffmpeg, but that doesn't reverse the audio. It keeps the audio intact and reverse the video

Answer (score 0):

```
moviepy.editor.vfx.time_mirror
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the method you have given, but I am getting the error                    ``` OSError: MoviePy error: failed to read the first frame of video file video1.mp4. That might mean that the file is corrupted. That may also mean that you are using a deprecated version of FFMPEG. On Ubuntu/Debian for instance the version in the repos is deprecated. Please update to a recent version from the website.
```